# Path of data on Google Cloud Platform for NiFi

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, apache-nifi

I want to give location of `input folder` in `GetFile` processor in `NiFi`. The path which I provided is incorrect according to `NiFi`. It still shows the warning sign. 
I followed  this [link](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7511998?hl=en) but it couldn't provide much help. Below is my path which I used in `input path` property in `GetFile` processor:

```
/browser/<bucket-name>/
```

I even tried below links

```
gs://<bucket-name>
```

or

```
gs://browser/<bucket-name>
```

None of them helped.

As suggested by Shu, I created one `ListGCSBucket` processor and created a new `GCPCredentialsService` for it but when I ran this processor it gives an error :
`com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Not Found` for bucket. Below are my few config: 
**Processor Details:**

[image]
[image]

**GCSControllerService Details:**
[image]
[image]

In the last image, it is not allowing me to change the values to `true`. So here are my complete details. Please guide where I am going wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add  warning logs to the question?

Comment: It shows invalid path exception

Comment: Do u have the path `/browser/<bucket-name>/` that specified in `GetFile`, **`on all NiFi installed nodes?`**

Comment: My data is in bucket on cloud.
So what would be the correct URL in this case for data which is under particular bucket

Comment: Thanks for clarification, i have added the answer to the question, please check the answer and let us know if there are any issues..!

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments on the question.

**`GetFile`** processor looks for `input path` that specified **on all NiFi installed nodes**.

Use [`ListGCSBucket`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-gcp-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.storage.ListGCSBucket/index.html) + [`FetchGCSObject`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-gcp-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.storage.FetchGCSObject/index.html) processors to get the data from GoogleCloudPlatform.

For more references refer [this](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/) and [this](https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/26ff675039e252d177b1195f3576cf9a) links to use list+fetch processors in nifi.

Comment: I have edited my question with screenshots. could you please help me out here ? Thanks

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar, **`disable`** the `GCPCredentialsControlerService` and then you are able to change the value to `true`. there is a post in nifi dev list regards to similar error: http://apache-nifi.1125220.n5.nabble.com/Connecting-Nifi-1-2-0-with-Google-Cloud-Storage-issue-td17225.html

Comment: Yeah I changed the value to true and I entered the right bucket path i guess but still it doesn't read the data when I start the processor. Can you provide me some sample

Comment: Any updates on this please ? can anyone help me here ?

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar, it seems to be we need to just give **`bucket name`** in `bucket` property value of **`ListGCSBucket`** processor instead of **`full url`**. some reference that will help: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/115115/nifi-gcpcredentialscontrollerservice-listgcsbucket.html  https://medium.com/datafabric/how-to-running-a-google-cloud-dataflow-job-from-apache-nifi-3fea8f9550

Comment: Yeah and what about controller service. What should be my value over there

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar, if `Use Application Default,ComputeEngine` credentials set to `False` then you need to generate `service account key file/json`.. (`Path to a file containing a Service Account key file in JSON format`) in this link i believe https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts.. please follow the steps that explained in detail in this thread.. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/115115/nifi-gcpcredentialscontrollerservice-listgcsbucket.html